# How to handle errors in node.js

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I know that in node, I can use `process.on('UncaughtException',evtHandlerFunction(){/*code*/});` but how do I go about handling errors "properly"? Like, whenever there's an error, send out a status code 500 on the current response stream of the request that the error occured when responding to and tell the user there was a problem. But I can't seem to figure out a good way to do this. How would I go about figuring out what the "current response stream" is, for example? I just want a concept of how to do this, I don't necessarily need code. Sorry if I was unclear, please post a comment if you don't understand.

Comment: Check out [node.js domains](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html). This doc also contains good general advice for handling errors on a node server.

Answer (score 0):

it totally depends on what kind of errors u want to handle.....
server errors can be http errors, socket errors, net errors etc.

each of these modules have an error handling code 
eg:

a socket server object has:

```
socket.on('error',function(err)
{
//code to handle
});
```

check out the detailed doc on site nodejs.org

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. I clearly said that I know how to know when there's an error, but I'm asking how to send out a 500 code and an error message to the current HTTP output stream.

Answer (score 0):

then u can use the response object as:

```
response.writeHead('500',{'Content_type':'text/plain'});
response.end('Your Error Message');
```

'your error message' will be the responseText for the client browser

Comment: Like I commented on your other question, this doesn't really answer the question. I know how to write to a stream, I'm just trying to figure out how, from an event listener, to retrieve the current stream so I can write to it. Also, I see you're new to SO, but just so you know instead of making new answers it's better just to edit existing answers using the small grey "edit" link/button below the answer

Comment: @Markasoftware so you need an event listener which may implement a callback wherein you can add ur changes to the stream??